# Discord API Error: 401: Unauthorized - Can't put application commands with REST

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I'm trying to build a discord bot with the slash command (Lastest Discord JS) but I'm facing some issues. Whenever I run my bot it says discord API error unauthorized 401.

Here is my bot code:

```js
import { config } from 'dotenv';
import {
    ActionRowBuilder,
    Client,
    GatewayIntentBits,
    InteractionType,
    ModalBuilder,
    Routes,
    // SelectMenuBuislder,
    TextInputBuilder,
    TextInputStyle,
} from 'discord.js';
import { REST } from '@discordjs/rest';
import pingCommand from './commands/ping.js'

config();

const TOKEN = process.env.BOT_TOKEN
const CLIENT_ID = process.env.CLIENT_ID;
const GUILD_ID = process.env.GUILD_ID;

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    ],
});

const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(TOKEN);

client.on('ready', () => console.log(`${client.user.tag} has logged in!`));


client.on('interactionCreate', (interaction) => {
    if (interaction.isChatInputCommand()) {
        console.log('Chat Command');
        if (interaction.commandName === 'ping') {
            interaction.reply("Pong")
        }
    }
});

async function main() {
    const commands = [
        pingCommand
    ];
    try {
        console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');
        await rest.put(Routes.applicationCommands(CLIENT_ID), {
            body: commands,
        });
        client.login(TOKEN);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

main();
```

`my ping command (for test) :`

```
import { SlashCommandBuilder } from '@discordjs/builders';

const pingCommand = new SlashCommandBuilder()
  .setName('ping')
  .setDescription('ping')
  .addRoleOption((option) =>
    option
      .setName('eh')
      .setDescription('huh')
      .setRequired(false)
  );

export default pingCommand.toJSON();
```

I've tried to use only the application commands module to prevent that because it requires only the client id instead of the client and guild id (as of applicaitonguildcommand). But the issue remains the same.

Comment: Have you debugged the values coming from `process.env`? Also, what version of `dotenv` are you using? Your usage differs from [the docs](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#how-do-i-use-dotenv-with-import)

Comment: @Phil dot env works fine. I've checked

Answer (score 3):

Probably you took token from **OAuth2 page** instead of **Bot page**.

Go to: [https://discord.com/developers/applications/{YOUR_APP_ID}/bot](https://discord.com/developers/applications/%7BYOUR_APP_ID%7D/bot) and click button `Reset token`. Token length will be in this format: `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.yyyyyy.zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz-qqqqqqqqq`.

[image]